# Is there a name for distributions induced by norms?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, terminology

The log density of a multivariate Gaussian is proportional to $||x-\mu||_2^2$, i.e. the norm of the difference between $x$, the random variable, and $\mu$, the mean of the distribution (assuming a covariance matrix of the form $\sigma^2 I$).

Gaussians are defined with $L_2$ norm. What about the general case of using other norms? Is there a name for such a distribution? For example, when the length of $x$ is 1 (univariate), then $||x-\mu||_1^2 = |x-\mu|$, and this would correspond to Laplace's distribution.

What about using $L_1$ norm for $x$ of larger length? What about using arbitrary norms?

Comment: For $L_2$, I'd say "spherically symmetric."

Comment: For $L_2$, it is just a Gaussian with cov $\sigma^2 I$. I am looking for the more general case, or at the very least, $L_1$.

Comment: You are choosing a particular function to apply to the norm, $\exp(-x^2)$ (up to scaling). Do you mean to restrict your question only to distributions of the form $\exp(-||x||^2),$ or are you allowing other functions?

Comment: yes, only distributions of the form $\exp(-||x||_p^p)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you clarify in a comment

> yes, only distributions of the form $\exp(-||x||_p^p)$.

I think that what you are after is [Generalized normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution), although that article further specializes the name as he symmetric generalized normal distribution, also known as the exponential power distribution or the generalized error distribution.

Comment: (1) The question is about *multivariate* distributions.  (2) Not all Norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are $L^p$ norms.